# Link Vscode with Intellij

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, visual-studio-code, sass

I wrote my frontend with Vscode(HTML, SASS and JS) and built my backend with Springboot in Intellij. How do I link them together? Or do I copy my frontend code into Intellij? I don't know if Springboot supports sass.
Please I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply open your frontend project in Intellij it will show you suggestion to install reqired plugins for your current project intall required plugins and that's it.

Comment: Please add screenshot of the solution

Comment: Let me try this out